# Trying to open .java and .xml files in Android Studio 321 it shows some error

Tags: android, android-studio

Am trying to open `.java` and `.xml` files in Android Studio 3.2.1 it shows some error related to `UTF-8 character set`.

I tried these

1.`Clean` the project

2.`Rebuild` the Project

3.`Invalidate and restart` and so many steps but error is not gone

Please find the attached document

[image]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Unmapable character encoding UTF-8 - Android Studio

1. Open Android Studio
2. Than look the bottom in right of android studio
3. You will see UTF-8
4. Than Click on, And select windows-1252(Something related to UTF)
5. Than Rebuild your project