# Java File is showing unknown characters

Tags: java, android

I am working on an app, But recently one of my Java file showing some unknown characters I also tried changing the encoding of a file but it not working, Is there any way that I can help me to get the file back?

screenshot of the problem I am facing now ...

[image]

expect that one file remaining all files are fine

```
Error Report

error: class, interface, or enum expected   
error: illegal character: '\u2649'  
error: illegal character: '\ufffd'  
error: illegal character: '\u16f6'  
error: illegal character: '\u1a5c'  
error: illegal character: '\uec94'  
error: illegal character: '\u202f'  
error: illegal character: '\u0f0c'  
error: illegal character: '\uf85f'  
error: illegal character: '\ufffd'  
error: illegal character: '\ufffd'  
error: illegal character: '\u2e0a'  
error: illegal character: '\u2976'  
error: illegal character: '\u2b69'  
error: illegal character: '\u33d4'  
error: illegal character: '\u24ed'  
error: illegal character: '\u1ca5'  
error: illegal character: '\u2938'  
error: illegal character: '\ufffd'  
error: illegal character: '\ufffd'  
error: illegal character: '\ufffd'  
error: illegal character: '\u4de6'
```

Thanks for help

Comment: These are the signs, my mistake.

Comment: do you have a backup copy?

Comment: No I don't have backup of it

Comment: This looks like it might be an encoding problem, unless of course you expect to be seeing Chinese characters in your file.

Comment: Is there any way to get it back? @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Check if your local history is available for this file or else you're out of luck.

Comment: In case it's just Android Studio getting confused about the character encoding, try opening the file with a text editor such as Notepad++.

Comment: I have tried it opening using the Notepad++ but the results are same...I am also out of luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When files show random characters like that it usually means there was an error in the compression or convertion of the file.
For example, if you take a Word document and open it in Notepad you'll see something similar to that.
If you have a backup or another copy I'd recommend trying that version.

Answer (score 0):

first try to Invalid Cashes/Restart Android Studio, if not resolved then try below way

[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53664291/8265484)

Comment: I tried Invalid Crashes but it not worked and The Second method is uninstalling and reinstalling android studio I am afraid that will also not work because when i open the file in notepad++ the code is still in unknown format

Comment: if you delete .idea, .dradle, build file and import again then may be you get original code

Answer (score 0):

The simple and the easy way.
Go to your folder location the app>src>main>java>com>
In general open your folder when you store your project then try to open the file with notepad or open code.
You will find your code, copy it and delete your old file.java and past it in a new java file have the same name

Answer (score 0):

first: create a backup of your project.
than:
you should delete android studio catch
for this --> open  C:\Users\plusg\AndroidStudio

for me : --> C:\Users\plusg\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2020.3

and just delete android studio catch. this folder not important just save android studio theme,font and etc.

now open your project again.